# How can I get the height of a specific item in my UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my `UICollectionView`  I've set different heights for different `cell` item using the delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch indexPath.item {
    case 0:
          return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width/2)
    case 1:
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 250)
    case 2:
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width/2)
    default:
         return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width)
    }

}
```

Now given a `indexPath`, I would like to get the height I've previously assigned for a specific `cell` Item .

Comment: Do you want to get size or set size? In question you have asked 'get' size in note at last you write 'set' size

Comment: @AdiHardik thanks ..  you want to get size

Comment: Updated the with both the case, may be it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can call the delegate method from your controller.

```
collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionView.collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)
```

Comment: I would like to get the height I've previously assigned for a specific Cell Item

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the UICollectionView and at later time you want to get height of any cell you can use below method to get the height of the cell

```
cellForItem(at:)
```

You can use this method with your UICollectionView object to get the cell at the particular index.
When you get any particular cell, you can check height of that cell using frame of the `contentView` inside that cell

[Apple Doc :UICollectionView cellForItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem)

---

If you want to update cell size after you set it first time you can call
 `invalidateLayout` method of collectionViewLayout property of your UICollectionView. This method regenerates your layout, which in your case means also calling `-collectionView: layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`, which is the right place to reflect your desired item size.

> **invalidateLayout**
>   Invalidates the current layout and triggers a layout update.
>
> You can call this method at any time to update the layout information.
>   This method invalidates the layout of the collection view itself and
>   returns right away. Thus, you can call this method multiple times from
>   the same block of code without triggering multiple layout updates. The
>   actual layout update occurs during the next view layout update cycle.

[Apple Doc: Invalidate layout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617728-invalidatelayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the `collectionViewLayout` for the layout attributes, which will give you the height, among other things:

```swift
let layoutAttributes = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
let height = layoutAttributes?.frame.height
```

Answer (score -1):

Use array to store size of each `cell`.

So when you wanted to know the previous size of `cell[i]` then it will be at position `array[i-1]`.

Comment: Yeah! make it global. As per your requirement.

Comment: typically i need to set dynamic size for case 1 .where i was that hard coded 250

Comment: @NazmulHasan Previous of `case 1` is `case 0`, so do code there.